# Add cookies in request module python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, module, request

I am scraping www.bing.com search engine, default it gives 10 results, but if we want more results, we can increased it by [setting](http://www.bing.com/account/general) in browser. Now I want more that 10 result using request module in python.To get **30** result we have to set **{NRSLT : 30}** in cookies.

**My code**

```
payload = {'q': "SACHIN", 'go' : 'Submit+Query', 'qs' : 'bs', 'form' : 'QBRE'}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'}

req = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", headers=headers, params=payload, timeout=10, cookies={'NRSLT' :'30'})

print req.cookies

<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie MUID=0EC3618FCAF862C41C6369B0CB4563A5 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHD=AF=QBRE for .bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20151013 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _EDGE_S=F=1&SID=3A5F411A73356B471C16492572886A84 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _EDGE_V=1 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _FS=NU=1 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _SS=SID=7DD3F0992D964941871C0C26DE81D3D2 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie MUIDB=0EC3618FCAF862C41C6369B0CB4563A5 for www.bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=00B888BB1B93486087FD9FE628581779 for www.bing.com/>]>
```

In this i am not getting key "NRSLT" set in cookies.Where I am going wrong?

Comment: For a more professional usage you could use [Bing Search API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingsearchapi) with a better defined interface.

Comment: free request to bing search api are very less

Comment: Why you are using Bing and not Google?

Comment: i am already using google and yahoo,want to go with bing now

Answer (score 0):

I would use an existing cookie to be sure that the page accepts the cookie. For this task you could use a [`Session` instance](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.0-0/user/advanced/) which already deals with the cookie for you implicitly.

```
# create a session object
s = requests.Session()
# retrieve a default cookie
s.get("https://bing.com")

# prepare the request parameters
payload = {'q': "SACHIN", 'go' : 'Submit+Query', 'qs' : 'bs', 'form' : 'QBRE'}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'}
# set the cookie variable NRSLT in the existing cookie
s.cookies.set("NRSLT", "50")
# sent prepared request to server
req = s.get("https://www.bing.com/search", headers=headers, params=payload, timeout=10)
```

Comment: when I do "print req.cookies" I get ouput as <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>

Comment: get <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie NRSLT=50 for />, <Cookie MUID=0D01780A21C26B90341E7035207F6A5C for .bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHD=AF=NOFORM for .bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20151013 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _EDGE_S=F=1&SID=3C639CC8D26D6B2E025F94F7D3D06A75 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _EDGE_V=1 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _FS=NU=1 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie _SS=SID=E76D347703DD42AE8DA3A4CA1110C4B4 for .bing.com/>, <Cookie MUIDB=0D01780A21C26B90341E7035207F6A5C for www.bing.com/>, <Cookie SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=76BCF508CBA144F5844C58D34AB84A7C for www.bing.com/>]>

Comment: In the code I set `s.cookies.set("NRSLT", "50")` and in your output there is `<Cookie NRSLT=50 for />`. Does the response text not include 50 results?